# Using UpdateLayeredWindow on a region of a window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm using UpdateLayeredWindow to create a layered window, and I've implemented drawing logic for the child controls. My problem is that every time a change occurs to the uI, the whole frame needs to be redrawn. I wondered if there was a way to only redraw a specific CRect or CRgn of the window (ie, passing the relevant CDC into UpdateLayeredWindow, but specifying the CRect you want to be invlidated).

Would using UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect, and setting the prcDirty CRect in the UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO struct, to the client area of the control, cause an update of only that area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `psize` and `pptSrc` parameters let you specify what portion of the window you want to update. `UpdateLayeredWindow` does not use an invalidation model. It uses an update model.

Comment: What about UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect function? It says that prcDirty RECT in the UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO param, is used to specify this, is this correct?

Comment: This is explained in the documentation. "The area to be updated. This parameter can be NULL. If it is non-NULL, only the area in this rectangle is updated from the source DC." It constrains the update region.

Comment: I know what the doc says, I just wanted some sort of validation that this actually works affectively and creates the desired affect.

Comment: It's not clear what effect you are trying to obtain. You talk about invalidation and update as if they are the same thing. You can control the update region (which pixels are changed as a result of the operation). You cannot control the invalidation region (which pixels are refreshed on screen as a result of the update). But there is no reason for you to care about the invalidation region, since you're not doing the painting.

Comment: I am trying to control the update, and invalidation. If I update a specific RECT, does this funciton invalidate the whole window or just that rect?

Comment: Where do I find information on the update model that it uses?

Comment: Um, the [Layered Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx) topic that is linked to from every layered window API?

Comment: I've read te documentation. I still don't realy understand whether using UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect to update the region of the window which has the control's bitmap drawn on it, is more efficient than call UpdateLayeredWindow and updating the whole window. Is there any other way of drawing controls? I have thought about making the layered window frame an inactive window and drawing the controls on a separate window ontop, but this just destroys the frame's alphablending... Help! :(

Comment: If you're looking to evaluate performance then there's only one way to know for sure: Try it both ways and compare.

Comment: Will Do:) just wondered if there was a standard method per say:) Thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 0):

"UpdateLayeredWindow always updates the entire window. To update part of a window, use the traditional WM_PAINT and set the blend value using SetLayeredWindowAttributes."
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556(v=vs.85).aspx

Please read the docs. Pleeeeease.

Comment: I need per-pixel alpha blending functionallity provided by UpdateLayeredWindow.

Answer (score 0):

> Would using UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect, and setting the prcDirty CRect in the UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO struct, to the client area of the control, cause an update of only that area?

Yes. This is exactly what it does.